# Left behind dialog box after a UserForm is closed in VBA

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

I have an Excel VBA UserForm that reproduces a flight log sheet, with several textboxes for each step of the flight, ignition, takeoff, landing, engines shutdown, etc…

To avoid inconsistencies, each textbox has its own filling rules that are checked in their respective Exit event. For example, some textboxes shall not be left empty.

In case the user causes an inconsistency, he(she) is allowed to repeat (correct) the information or cancel the check, overriding it. Such design was needed in cases where the user mistakenly clicked another textbox and had to override the check to return to the correct textbox.
The code is:

```
answer = MsgBox("INCORRECT OR MISSING INFO.", 5 Or 16 Or 0, "WARNING !"

Select Case answer
Case 4
UserForm1.Textbox1.value = ""
                    Cancel = True
Case 2
    End Select
```

The problem: if the user chooses to click the button to exit the UserForm (unload it in the code), aborting the filling process, and the focus was on one of those textboxes, the UserForm closes, and the user is presented to the dialog box:

INCORRECT OR MISSING INFO.
[Repeat] [Cancel]

So far so good, If the user chooses “Cancel”, everything is fine. But if he(she) is creative enough and chooses to “Repeat” the information with the UserForm already closed (not a coherent behavior) the system crashes with the following error message:

Run-time error ‘-2147024809 (80070057)’
Could not find the specified object.

Obviously the system cannot find or set focus to something that does not exist anymore, since the UserForm was unloaded.

The question: is there a way to deal with such a weird although likely to occur situation?

I thought that once a UserForm was unloaded, every process related to it would be forced to close as well.

I have tried to deal with focus related properties, flags to indicate that the last focused control was of that type in order to enable or not the Exit button... nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the gigantic message.

Comment: Hello again...after posting my very first question here, I found a simple workaround that, for the time being, solves the problem of a "creative user": I deleted the line UserForm1.Textbox1.value = "" and there the crash vanished even if the user chooses to repeat the info after closing the form. It seems I was triggering the problem with that line. Yet, I am still curious about a way of forcing open dialog boxes related to an unloaded userform to close. Thank you again.

Comment: I typically set a flag to not do the event when the app is closing down.

Comment: Would you be better just hiding the form until you can ascertain that the user has actually finished and only then unloading the form.